# Limiting behavior of $x$ given that $ 1=\sum^N_{i=1}\frac{\alpha_i}{x+M\alpha_i} $ as $N,M\rightarrow\infty$?

Tags: limits, asymptotics, mathematical-physics, limits-without-lhopital, implicit-function-theorem

Consider the following implicit equation for $x$.
$$ 1=\sum^N_{i=1}\frac{\alpha_i}{x+M\alpha_i} $$
I am trying to see what a limiting behavior of $x$ is, as $N$ and $M$ explode to infinity. I require that $M/N = \mathcal{O}(1)$, as $N\rightarrow\infty$ and $M\rightarrow\infty$. I also assume that $\alpha_i = \mathcal{O}(1)$.

My gut feeling is that $x=\mathcal{O}(N)$, but I am not sure how to arrive at this result in a rigorous fashion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will make additional assumptions:

> **Assumption.** $N \geq M$ and $\alpha_i > 0$ for each $i$.

Now define $f(x)$ by the sum in the right-hand side:

$$ f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{\alpha_i}{x + M\alpha_i}. $$

Clearly, $f(x)$ is a strictly decreasing function for $x \geq 0$. Also, let $S = \sup_i \alpha_i$ and note that $S < \infty$ by OP's assumption. Then

$$
f(SN)
= \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{\alpha_i}{SN + M\alpha_i}
\leq \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{\alpha_i}{SN}
\leq 1, $$

whereas

$$ f(0)
= \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{\alpha_i}{M\alpha_i}
= \frac{N}{M}
\geq 1. $$

Since $f$ is strictly decreasing on $[0, \infty)$, there exists a unique non-negative solution of $f(x) = 1$, and that unique solution lies in the interval $[0, SN]$.

Comment: Thank you so much. I forgot to add the assumption that $\alpha_i>0$ for all $i$, but you serendipitously found that the assumption is useful. Would there be a possible analysis for the limiting behavior for the case $N<M$ as well? I picture that the solution for $x$ would be negative, and my intuition is that it can't grow as fast as the case where $N>M$, based on a graph I doodled...

Comment: @CWC, Here is a quick observation: Note that $f(x) \to \infty$ as $x$ tends to $a := -M \min\{\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_N\}$ from the right. So, the negative solution of $f(x) = 0$ that is "closest" to $0$ must be bounded from below by $a$.

Comment: Do you mean $f(x)=1$?

Comment: Ouch, yes. I mean $f(x)=1$.

Comment: Hmmm I see that if $x<\mathcal{O}(N)$, then the solution can be satisfied only if $N=M$. Does this mean the solution for $x$ can be any real number as long as $x<\mathcal{O}(N)$, if $N=M$?